# Issue when trying to create a sendgrid account on azure server

Tags: azure, sendgrid

I am trying to use sendgrid on azure, but when I am creating the account, it gives me an error saying:

*The portal is having issues getting an authentication token. The experience rendered may be degraded.
Additional information from the call to get a token:
Extension: SendGrid_EmailService
Details: code: 500, statusText: error, message: There was an error processing your request. Please try again in a few moments., stack:*

It has been giving me this since morning, pretty annoyed. And also it disables two fields, and marks them as loading:

[Screenshot of the two fields marked as loading (For a very long time)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKFkk.png)

Since sendgrid wasnt working I thought I'd try and use SparkPost- The signup was successful, but its been taking hours to deploy.
Then I thought of manually configuring the smtp settings so the host and user and stuff could be sendgrid, but I wasnt able to find a way to do so.

Could someone help me out please! Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT:** This problem has been solved by the Microsoft Team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to enter to SendGrid using the following steps from [Aaryaman Maheshwari in this comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/comments/177652/view.html):

Steps from Aaryaman's answer:

> Step 1: In order to find ur username for SendGrid, first, go to the
> SendGrid resource and then click properties. Now copy the resource id.
>
> Step 2: Now, in the azure online shell, open bash and type the
> following command: az resource show --ids [THE COPIED RESOURCE ID]
>
> Make sure to replace [THE COPIED RESOURCE ID] with the resource Id you
> copied in step 1
>
> Step 3: In the json string that the terminal outputs, look for the
> username property and note that down
>
> Step 4: After you do that you can manually go to sendgrid.com and then
> enter the username you just retrieved and then the password which you
> used to sign up with.

Thanks Aaryaman Maheshwari

Answer (score 3):

Looks like SendGrid has some technical problems. You should check first SendGrid official support website if this is the issue. I was using SendGrid for a while, but I had to move to another solution. When you are registering SendGrid account via Azure you getting standard SendGrid plan. That means that you are sending your mails through shared SendGrid IPs. This is probably ok for marketing emails, but if you intend to send any transactional emails like password reset, bills etc you will end up eventually with tearing your hair off the head, because shared SendGrid IPs are in most existing spam blacklists out there.

[SendGrid app status](https://status.sendgrid.com/)

Comment: Thank you! I think the problem is on azures end so I guess my best chance right now would be to use PHPmailer. I did try putting up the exact same question on microsoft Q&A tho... hopefully they reply soon but idk if they will as its not as vast as stackoverflow, where you can get replies within an hour :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to incresase security, Sendgrid has recently requested to enable 2 factors authentication to connect to your account (it started one or two weeks ago).
Since this moment, the "automatic" connection from Azure to Sendgrid stopped to succes, and we have the same 500 error.
Also, "basic authentication" (username / password) will stop to work (starting from 10 decemeber I believe) in your api.
I'm not sure this is the reason, but it happens at the same time ;)

Comment: Yes Gutazo. If you'd like, refer to @Enrique Zavaleta's answer. He has quoted the solution I put up for this on the Microsoft Q&A. Also, the initial problem has been fixed on the main portal.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update:

There was bug identified on Azure Portal and our product engineering team have fixed the issue.

Provisioning SendGrid account via https://portal.azure.com/ and managing works as expected.
The alternate https://rc.portal.azure.com/ URL was shared during the impact and is no longer required to be used.

We had a discussion on [Q&A thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/169369/index.html). Once again apologies for all the inconvenience. Much appreciate the follow-up and great collaboration.

[image: In case, if anyone sees this issue, kindly let us know.]